# d3js pie, refreshing labels position on slices, on pie transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I'm experimenting with d3js pie layout. I've managed to make transformation of a pie according to multiple data items. And placing a label for each item in center of a slice.

You can see my example on following link: http://jsfiddle.net/ahbqP/

The script looks like this:

```
var data_1 = [
              {"A": 43, "B": 10, "C":3, "D": 29, "E": 500},
              {"A": 20, "B": 2, "C":4, "D": 39, "E": 400 },
              {"A": 17, "B": 5, "C":6, "D": 19, "E": ""},
              {"A": 20, "B": 2, "C":2, "D": 69, "E": ""},
             ]

var width_1 = 500,
    height_1 = 400,
    radius_1 = Math.min(width_1, height_1) / 2;

var color_1 = d3.scale.category20c();

var pie_1 = d3.layout.pie()
    .value(function(d) { return d.A; })
    .sort(null);

var arc_1 = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius_1 - 100)
    .outerRadius(radius_1 - 20);

var svg_1 = d3.select(".pie_container_1").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width_1)
    .attr("height", height_1)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width_1 / 2 + "," + height_1 / 2 + ")");

var path_1 = svg_1.datum(data_1).selectAll("path")
      .data(pie_1)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "slice")
      .append("path")
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color_1(i); })
      .attr("d", arc_1)
      .each(function(d) { this._current = d; }); // store the initial angles


var pText = svg_1.selectAll(".slice")
    .append("text")
    .attr("class","val")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                d.innerRadius = 0;
                d.outerRadius = radius_1;
                return "translate(" + arc_1.centroid(d) + ")";
            })
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .data(data_1)
    .text(function(d) { return d.A + "%"; });

  d3.selectAll("input")
      .on("change", change_1);


function change_1() {
    var value_1 = this.value;
    // clearTimeout(timeout_1);
    pie_1.value(function(d) { return d[value_1]; }); // change the value function

    path_1 = path_1.data(pie_1); // compute the new angles

    var pathT = path_1.transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", arcTween_1); // redraw the arcs

    pText = svg_1.selectAll(".slice").select(".val").attr("transform", function(d) {
                d.innerRadius = 0;
                d.outerRadius = radius_1;
                return "translate("+ arc_1.centroid(d) +")";
            })
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .data(data_1)
    .text(function(d) { 
                        if( value_1 == "E" && d.E != "" ){ return d.E + "%"; }
                        if( value_1 == "D" ){ return d.D + "%"; }
                        if( value_1 == "C" ){ return d.C + "%"; }
                        if( value_1 == "B" ){ return d.B + "%"; }
                        if( value_1 == "A" ){ return d.A + "%"; }

                      });
  }

// Store the displayed angles in _current.
// Then, interpolate from _current to the new angles.
// During the transition, _current is updated in-place by d3.interpolate.
function arcTween_1(a) {
  var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
  this._current = i(0);
  return function(t) {
    return arc_1(i(t));
  };
}
```

Everything is working ok, except one thing. The placement of text labels after calling `change_1` function. They stay on the previous position, because I don't know how to set up new position values. On load I'm setting them up with:

```
.attr("transform", function(d) {
            d.innerRadius = 0;
            d.outerRadius = radius_1;
            return "translate(" + arc_1.centroid(d) + ")";
        })
```

but calling that same thing in `change_1` does not move them. I assume that I must calculate some other centroid value but I don't know how exactly...

What it takes to move them altogether with new sizes of arcs on change_1 function?

You can edit my fiddle, any help or advice is welcome...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You weren't updating the data bound to the `text` elements before changing the position, only afterwards. Hence, the position wasn't updated.

I've updated your change code to do the data binding before setting the position as follows.

```
pText = svg_1.selectAll(".val").data(pie_1).attr("transform", function(d) {
                d.innerRadius = 0;
                d.outerRadius = radius_1;
                return "translate("+ arc_1.centroid(d) +")";
            })
```

Complete jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ahbqP/2/). On a general note, it would be better practice if you selected the elements that you are then appending (i.e. not select `.slice` and then append `.val`), as I've done in the updated code. This makes it much easier to debug the code and understand what's going on.

Oh and setting attributes as a side effect (i.e. the radii inside the function to set the `transform`) isn't good practice either.

Comment: never thought that this was the issue...thank you Lars! You are a legend! :)